# Django: Converting a GenericForeignKey Relationship to a ForeignKey Relationship

Tags: django

I'm working to remove an existing GenericForeignKey relationship from some models. Id like to change it to the Reformatted Model below.  Does migrations provide a way to convert the existing content_type and object_ids to the respective new ForeignKey's? (to keep existing data). Basically brand new at programming, so pardon me if I'm asking a stupid question.

```
class Donation(models.Model):
    amount_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True, editable=False)
    date_issued=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type','object_id')

class Individual(BaseModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, 
    null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    suffix = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    contributor = generic.GenericRelation(Donation, related_query_name='individual')


class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contributor = generic.GenericRelation(Donation, related_query_name='organization')
```

Reformatted Model

```
class Donation(models.Model):
    amount_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True, editable=False)
    date_issued=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    contributor_group = models.ForeignKey(Organization, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contributor_individual = models.ForeignKey(Individual, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your model definition of Donation Model, one of fields contributor_group , contributor_model will always be Null post migration.
I hope you have taken that into you consideration.

Just to be safe Do this in two phases.
1. Keep the content_type and object_id and add the two new fields.
2. Next step remove the generic fields post data population.

There are two ways to populate those new fields

1. Django migrations provides you a way to populate new fields with values during the migrations. You can look it up. I haven't done that before either.
2. For more control and some learning as well. You can populate that via scripting as well. You can setup django-extensions module in your project. And write a script to do that population for you as well. A sample script would look like.

   from myproject.models import Donation, Individual, Organization
   from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

   def run():
       organization_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Organization)
       individual_content_type = ContentType.obejcts.get_for_model(Individual)

   ```
   donations  = Donation.objects.all()
   for donation in donations:
        if donation.content_type_id == organization_content_type.id:
              donation.contributor_group = donation.object_id
        elif donation.content_type_id == individual_content_type.id:
              donation.contributor_individual = donation.object_id
        else:
             print "Can't identify content type for donation id {}".format(donation.id)
        donation.save()
   ```

Check the values are correct and then remove the generic fields. 
Facing some issues with formatting here.